# How to mod_rewrite just one querystring parameter?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I would like to rewrite the following URL:

```
mypage/1234/myaction?api_key=4567
```

to:

```
api/myaction.php?id=1234&api_key=4567
```

...using mod-rewrite. I can get /mypage/1234/myaction -> api/myaction.php?id=1234, but the extra get parameter is causing some problems....

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see what you've got so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `QSA` (query string append) flag:

```
RewriteRule mypage/(\d+)/myaction api/myaction.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: This is a super old answer - But I agree. This is the correct answer. Thanks!